# Slow performance with ListView in Windows XP

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, windows-xp

So an application I am designing uses a very simple list view that contains check boxes to check off certain items on the list.  It runs perfectly fine on my machine with windows 7, but when running it on a different machine with windows XP, the mouse gets very slow and choppy when hovering around the check boxes.  I wrote an app that is purely a listview with check boxes with absolutely nothing else in the project and it still does the same thing.  Is there something wrong with this...?

```
<ListView Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding List}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView >
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Dummy Column"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Dummy Column2"/>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Bool}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The app runs fine otherwise on the XP machine, just gets slow when hovering over the check boxes and I'm not really sure why.  Anybody ever experienced this or know what causes it/easy solutions?

Comment: What happens if you rebuild your app in .NET 4.0 / 3.5 on XP and then run it over there?

Comment: I can try to build it from XP I suppose, going to have to wait till tomorrow though and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the style/template for your checkboxes, are you animating the hover effects with storyboards or the VSM, or are you swapping out brushes with triggers? If you're animating them, try just swapping brushes instead. For some reason XP doesn't always handle WPF animations well.

Comment: I'm not doing anything special, literally you can take this xaml code with nothing else in the project and it was running slow on an otherwise reasonably decent XP machine.

Comment: Test it by animating the background of a border or grid on mouseover and see if you get a similar issue. For my last project, we deployed a separate XP skin that removed every built-in animation because of performance issues.

Comment: What's an easy way to remove the built-in animation of a control?

Comment: By altering the ControlTemplate in your skin. Also, you might want to take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rendercapability.tier.aspx Occasionally a client will have a machine that absolutely tanks on performance, and running this usually shows a 0 or a 1. Not the best test, but helpful if the hardware should be able to push the graphics but can't for whatever reason.